# Is an input-output model an equilibrium model?

Tags: general-equilibrium, input-output

I know the difference between CGE and input-output models. 
But can an input-output model be called a equilibrium model?

Comment: This site says input-output covers the demand-side  and assume there are no capacity constraints  https://www.gov.scot/publications/cge-modelling-introduction/     .  Not sure if an input-output can be called an equilibrium model.

Comment: My guess is yes if you can find particular solutions that satisfy it. What exactly is your intention after classifying it as an equilibrium model?

Comment: I think you are right, Mike J. Thanks both for your answer! :-)